# Override system hotkeys (shortcuts) for switching between apps and tabs in MacOS 10.15

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, alfred, karabiner

I am using *MacOS* 10.15.6 and already setup keyboard's system preferences to swap modifier keys. I swap *Command* and *Control* keys already. At the moment, with this new re-map applied, I must hit, `Control+Tab` to switch among opened **apps** and `Command+Tab` to switch among opened **tabs** (in browsers, terminal, file editors and etc).

This is very uncomfortable and irritating for me. I would like to change that, and have it done in my *MacOS* just the same way I have it done in *Gnome* (*Fedora Linux*), which is `Option+Tab` for switching between **apps** and `Control+Tab` for switching **tabs**. Holding *Shift* should also work to reverse it.

I use *Alfred* for creating other hotkeys workflows and know about *Karabiner-Elements* app - I just wanted to have it swapped in a way that wouldn't require creating any virtual keyboards or anything extra like that, for example, using `defaults` command or something else more native? Doing it using *Alfred* would also be suitable for me, as I am already running it but *Alfred*  doesn't seem to be able to override system wide shortcuts?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Speaking as a user of Mac, nix & Win for 30 years, I'm tempted to say you're just making a rod for your own back. Why not just learn the paradigm shift instead of trying to fight it. It really won't help, long-term.

Comment: Well, any paradigm shift must be driven by underlying development. :-)

"It really won't help, long-term" - What do you mean by that? How do you work around it? Perhaps, you want me to become both effective using different hotkeys, in different OSes?

Comment: That's the long & short of it, yes. As the Americans say, "you can't fight city hall". Aside from the fact it's not really possible to completely WinKey a Mac or voce versa [you'll fall down on system-wide commands & in Terminal-type apps especially] if you ever have to hot-desk or use someone else's machine, you'll be doubly lost. I swap between Win & Mac all day long; after a time you really do just learn it.

Comment: I get your point. I use only computers setup by me - desktops (static) and laptop (mobile). I don't use Windows anymore at all. Actually, I managed to overcome MacOS Terminal differences compared to Linux and make it work as expected. For example, to make `Ctrl+left` act as in Linux, instead of doing something else fancy. Same for `Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V`, `home`, `end` and etc. it's doable and makes my workflow blazingly fast. It's all about speed and smoothness. I can setup Karabiner and make it work needed way. I just don't understand Apple and why it's not easily configurable. Hope 10.16 fixes it.

Comment: ..in the end, it's unfair to pay thousands of dollars to Apple, and suffer from not having such both crucial and easy to implement feature.

Comment: You have to bear in mind these competing standards were set up in the mid 80s. They converged slightly with common commands for such as cut, copy, paste, but Apple had one more modifier than anyone else, so they used that. I doubt you're going to find much more convergence, unless Apple suddenly decide to drop the Cmd key after 35 years. Just learn the difference, it's really not that hard. I've been doing it since the 90s.

Comment: I know about competition - it's just mean to pour it on the end user, which pays their bills! I don't want them to drop _Cmd_ key in any way. I just expect that we, being MacOS users, could change _Cmd+Tab_ to _Option+Tab_ for switching apps and _Control+Tab_ to _Cmd+Tab_ for switching tabs. "Just learn the difference, it's really not that hard." - Thanks, but I know about all of the differences, it's not just about knowing, it's about muscle memory.

Comment: Each company gives not one jot about what their competitors do. Apple is now twice the size of Microsoft… not that they cared even when they were half the size, & bear in mind we had the Mac a long time before anyone even glanced twice at Windows. Unix in all its myriad flavours doesn't count at all, except it's built on the same hardware that Windows runs on.  Complain all you like, but the only person taking any notice at all of all this is… me.

Comment: This is unfortunate; and believe me, not all companies don't care - it's all about engineers working in it. I bet most developers use GNU Linux with Gnome (KDE or whatever), instead of lame MacOS with FreeBSD. Those Linux GDEs use key maps I mentioned on the initial issue. It's not about competition, it's about respect to the buyers. Thank you for being that only person. :-)

Comment: According to stack exchange, it's 50% win, 25% mac & nix. You still seem to be demanding entitlement to have any system your way. Not going to happen. We Mac users would like to coerce Win & Nix to be more like we're used to… not gonna happen either. And please don't turn your annoyance into disrespect for users of other platforms. Calling any OS "lame" shows total disregard for those who may prefer it, & is certain to get people's backs up in a predominantly Apple-oriented site as this. If you don't like it, don't use it, but don't call it lame just because you're used to something different.

Comment: Look, I called it "lame" in terms of having FreeBSD under the hood. MacOS is technically exploiting it. It's not meant to be offensive, as those who ever used GNU versions of `grep`, `find`, `kill`, `sed` and etc will certainly agree, and in-fact the word "lame" is very soft in this regard. :-) If a user uses MacOS to surf the web, edit photos or videos, than okay, you can live with any hotkeys but if you're in a seriously development on _both_ Linux and MacOS at the same time, then you're in trouble, due to muscle memory, without having a flexibility to change bloody key maps.

Comment: Then why not just change the nix maps instead?

Comment: This is a fair question. I indeed decided to go down this way few days ago, saying to my self, darn it, I will force myself to re-learn it. The good thing was, that Gnome indeed allowed changing hotkeys for switching apps but I couldn't find the way to change hotkeys for changing tabs, which defaults to _Ctrl+Tab_. In other words, I managed making it work the way it is currently working in MacOS for changing apps but couldn't find the way to do the same for changing tabs. Duh. Bummer. I guess I should switch to using KDE or build a widget for Gnome to accommodate Apple's inhuman decisions. :-D